# scanf expect 3 values insted of 2

Tags: c

i want to input two numbers as lower limit(ll) and upper limit (ul) and want to find out all prime numbers between these limits.but when i try to run the program  scanf function expect 3 input instead of 2.

here is the code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int number,i,ll,ul;
    printf("enter the 2 numbers\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&ll,&ul);
    for(number=ll;number<=ul;number++)
    {    
        for(i=2;i<number;i++)
        {
            if(number%i==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }

        if(i==number)
        {
            printf("%d  is prime \n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the space from the `scanf`'s format string:`scanf("%d%d",&ll,&ul);` But I don't see how that would ask for *extra* input. Perhaps, you have space at the *end* like: `scanf("%d%d ",&ll,&ul);` ?

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine? http://ideone.com/ZInND9